# How do you send data to socket with different emit?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I want to send data to 2 different components using socket.io, now the first emit works but the second isn't even activated, I tried to invert the order of them inside io.on function and only the first written one works. Is the second waiting for the first emit to end? How can I make them work in parallel?

This is my code:

```
import {createServer} from "http";
import socketIo from "socket.io";
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { MONGODB_URL } from "./config/config";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { watchLeaves } from "./database/controllers/LeaveControllers";
import { watchCalendars } from "./database/controllers/calendarControllers";

const port = process.env.PORT || 3333;

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send({ response: "I am a websocket!" }).status(200);
});

const verifySocketAuth = (header) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof header !== "undefined") {
        const headerArray = header.split(" ")
        const token = headerArray[1]
        return jwt.verify(token, "Bearer", (err, auth) => {
            if (err) reject(new Error(err))
            else resolve(auth)
        })
    }
})

const server = createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    }
});

io.use(async (socket, next) => {
    const header = socket.handshake.headers["authorization"];
    await verifySocketAuth(header)
    console.log("token", await verifySocketAuth(header))
    next()
});

const getLeavesAndEmit = async (socket) => {
    const lastRecord = await watchLeaves();
    socket.emit("FromLeaves", lastRecord);
};

const getCalendarsAndEmit = async (socket) => {
    const lastRecord = await watchCalendars();

    console.log("last record calendars==>", lastRecord);
    socket.emit("FromCalendars", lastRecord);
};
io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
    console.log("Client connected");
    
    await getLeavesAndEmit(socket);
    await getCalendarsAndEmit(socket);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Client disconnected");
    });
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Soket Server listening on ${port}`));
```

Comment: I guess `socket.emit` doesn't return a Promise, so when you do `await getLeavesAndEmit(socket)` you are awaiting something that will never resolve? After `socket.emit` try to return something static from your async function, like `return "done"`

Comment: Oh nice :) That was a shot in the dark. I've posted it as an answer, so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `socket.emit` doesn't return a Promise, so when you do `await getLeavesAndEmit(socket)` you are awaiting something that will never resolve. After `socket.emit` try to return something static from your async function, like `return "done"`